# How are inbox items counted?

Tags: support, user-interface, notifications

Sometimes my inbox icon lights up with a red number, say "3", but when I click on it I see only 2 items highlighted.  Sometimes when I follow the link I find that what seemed to be just 1 item is in fact 2 comments on the same question or answer, so that resolves the discrepancy, but other times I can't figure out what the 3rd item is.  How are inbox items counted?  I'm wondering if I'm missing some things.

Comment: I am not sure how to answer the question you actually ask, but the following might address the underlying concern: http://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox shows all in-box items (no "merge" of items). You can also get there by clicking "see all inbox items" at the end of the dropdown from the topbar. A final remark: there is some delay with delete items. So a deleted comment might still show/count in the inbox, yet not on the site.

Comment: My experience suggests they are grouped by question and just the questions are listed, so I see a number 3 might represent two (unread) comments tied to one question and one to another question.  However, this is a perception, not a conclusion based on meticulous observation.  Gerhard "Preferes Meticulously Observing Other Things" Paseman, 2015.09.04

Comment: @quid : the deleted comment is an interesting suggestion and I think that is the best explanation so far.

Comment: Thanks for  the feedback on the experiment. Me too, I just got two entries for your two comments. It thus seems that at east separate posts are handled separately.

Comment: Maybe we can get some combinatorialist to look into that. These guys are all about counting stuff! :-)